# Columns selection from external query within main query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a unique requirement.

```
select A.Column1, 
       B.Column2, 
       (Select c.column3||':'||c.column4 from TableC c) as C_INFO  
from TableA A, TableB B 
where A.COLUMNX = B.COLUMNX;
```

The above one is my current query gives returns

- Column1 from TableA,
- Column2 from Table B,
- Column3:Column4(concatenate) from Table C.

The question here is: can I get those columns from C individually, rather than concatenating them to one column?

Answer (score 0):

if you have join key on table C then use join explicitly then select any column of table c by using join with others table, here i guess you have a columnx in table c and i have given join with table A

```
    select A.Column1,
    B.Column2,
    C.Column3,
    (Select c.column3||':'||c.column4 from TableC c) 
    as C_INFO         
   TableA A join  
   TableB B 
   on B.COLUMNX=A.COLUMNX
   join TableC C on A.COLUMNX=C.COLUMNX
```